# Facebook video cannot be embedded

Tags: facebook

I have a problem embeding cerain videos in my website. Video I uploaded few mounths ago, and was embeded perfectly now shows a dark blue screen with the message "this video cannot be embedded". I checked with other videos I found, they all seams to work with my code. I tried "editing" the video on facebook, and there is a check box "Prohibit embedding", which is not selected. Baside that, I couldn't find anything related.
Why can't I embed my video?